# Powershell: Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "" because a member with that name already exists

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to pull some information using PowerShell and racadm from Dell servers. The script is below, and I am not able to append with new chassis/blade info...

I tried `Select-Object` instead but then the `Export-Csv` does not show values, instead it shows up as `System.Object[]`.

```
##################################################
# Variables that need to be set for script to work
#Path to RACADM Executable
$racadmpath = "C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\rac5"
# Username and Password for DRAC Account with configure access. Suggested that this
# be set in the script you which to use with, or configured as script command line
# arguments for security.

$username = *****
$pass = *******
$ipchbld = Import-Csv 'ipCHBLD.csv'
#####################################################################################

$MyCollection = @()
foreach ($ip in $ipchbld) {
    $arrayobj = @()
    $object = New-Object PSObject
    $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Chassis Slot" -value $ip.Chassis_Slot
    $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DRAC IP" -value $ip.DRAC_IP
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getchassiname | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Chassis Name" -value $line[0]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getsvctag | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "" -And $line -match "Chassis") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Chassis Service Tag" -value $line[1]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -m cmc-1 | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CMC" -value $line[0]
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CMC Version" -value $line[1]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -m cmc-2 | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CMC" -value $line[0]
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CMC Version" -value $line[1]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getslotname | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Blade Slot" -value $line[1]
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Blade Name" -value $line[2]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -c | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "" -ANd $line -match "server") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Blade Type" -value $line[2]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getsvctag | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "" -And $line -match "Server") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Blade Service Tag" -value $line[1]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f bios | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "BIOS" -value $line[2]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f idrac | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "iDRAC" -value $line[2]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f usc | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Unified Server Configurator" -value $line[2]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f diag | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "32-bit Diagnostics" -value $line[2]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f drivers | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OS Driver Package" -value $line[3]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f nic | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "" -ANd $line -match "server") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NIC Type" -value $line[1]
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NIC FW Version" -value $line[9]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -l -f raid | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "" -ANd $line -match "Controller 0") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PERC H700 Modular" -value $line[6]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion -c | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "" -ANd $line -match "server") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CPLD Version" -value $line[1]
            }
            }
    $output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getkvminfo | select -Skip 8
    foreach ($line in $output) {
        if ($line -ne "") {
            $line = $line -replace '\s+', ','
            $line = $line.Split(",")
            $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "iKVM FW Version" -value $line[5]
            }
            }
    $arrayobj += $object
    }
$MyCollection += $arrayobj
$MyCollection | Export-Csv "C:\FWReport\CHBLD.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not parsing the output of racadm.exe properly, but without knowing what it looks like it's impossible to tell.

Comment: The out put is okay cause the first line is properly displayed, but the second line does not get added and the error is - Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "" because a member with that name already exists. If you wa
nt to overwrite the member anyway, use the Force parameter to overwrite it.

Comment: Here is what the output looks like in csv

"Chassis Slot","DRAC IP","Chassis Service Tag","CMC","CMC Version","Blade Slot","Blade Name","Blade Type","Blade Service Tag","BIOS","iDRAC","Unified Server Configurator","32-bit Diagnostics","OS Driver Package","NIC Type","NIC FW Version","CPLD Version","iKVM FW Version"
"Chassis #####","x.x.x.x","xxxxx","cmc-1","4.11.A01.201205162137","1","server.domain.com","PowerEdge","xxxx","6.3.0","3.42","1.5.5.27","5157A0","6.4.0.17","NIC-Broadcom","7.2.20","1.0.3","01.00.01.01"

Comment: and then it just keeps failing for each parameter with the add-member cannot add error

Answer (score 0):

Are you confident that `$output` only contains a single non-empty line with the data you're interested in?  If not, your `foreach ($line in $output) {}` will attempt to add the same property name twice.  You might throw in a `break` statement to make sure that doesn't happen.

```
$output = & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getchassiname | select -Skip 8
foreach ($line in $output) {
    if ($line -ne "") {
        $line = $line -split '\s+'
        $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Chassis Name" -value $line[0]
        break
    }
}
```

To handle the case where the property already exists (append the data) try this:

```
$prop = 'ChassisName'
if ($object.psobject.properties[$prop]) {
    $object.$prop += $line[0]
}
else {
    $object | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $prop -value $line[0]
}
```

BTW drop the spaces in the property names to make your life a bit easier.  :-)

Update:  I don't have racadm.exe to run so I'm guessing on its output.  Try this:

```
$MyCollection = @()
foreach ($ip in $ipchbld) {
    $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                  ChassisSlot=$ip.Chassis_Slot
                  ChassisIP=$ip.DRAC_IP
                  ChassisName=''
                  ChassisSvcTag=@('')
                  CMC=@('')
                  CMCVersion=@('')}

    & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getchassisname | 
        Select -Skip 8 | Where {$_} | 
        Foreach {$object.ChassisName = ($_ -replace '\s+',',' -split ',')[0]}

    & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getsvctag | 
        Select -Skip 8 | Where {$_ -match 'Chassis'} | 
        Foreach {$object.ChassisSvcTag += ($_ -replace '\s+',',' -split ',')[1]}

    & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion | 
        Select -Skip 60 | Where {$_} | 
        Foreach {$object.CMC += ($_ -replace '\s+',',' -split ',')[0]}

    & $racadmpath\racadm.exe -r $ip.DRAC_IP -u $username -p $pass getversion | 
        Select -Skip 60 | Where {$_} | 
        Foreach {$object.CMCVersion += ($_ -replace '\s+',',' -split ',')[1]}

    $MyCollection += $object
}

$MyCollection
$MyCollection | Export-Csv "C:\Users\FWReport\CHBLD.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Keith, yes you are right $output will contain 16 lines for blades and 2 lines for cmc for every loop of "foreach ($ip in $ipchbld) {} , so yes the $output will have 16 lines for each loop of these and every $output after wards the member "Blade Slot". The break would skip the next blades and will record only data for a single blade in the chassis, but when a chassis is pulled for data I will start getting the error again. I would like to add lines of data to the same property. How can I do that?

Comment: So what I would like is for each new blade it should be able to add a new row to the existing column. And then when it pulls info for a new chassis, it should add to that row onwards. All I need is the Add-member to add new lines below the existing one under the same header, starting from an empty row.

Comment: I really appreciate you guys taking a look and trying to help me out. I am really grateful for the tips.

Comment: Keith, thank you. I tried what you suggested and please see my answer below. I did remove the spaces :-). Learning all the way ;-)